# "Shell Command Language" document - a counterintuitive sentence in "Token Recognition" section

Tags: shell, sh, posix

In section 2.3 ("Token Recognition") of this document: https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2008edition/utilities/V3_chap02.html
the following sentence appears:

**"If it is indicated that a token is delimited, and no characters have been included in a token, processing shall continue until an actual token is delimited"**

What's this supposed to mean? How can a token be marked as delimited before any character has been included in it?

Answer (score 0):

That sentence does appear ambiguous. Reworded it says "If a token is empty, processing continues until a non-empty token is given."

A token is 'marked as delimited' when its beginning and end are known. So from the last delimiter to the newly found delimiter.

A token can be empty if there are 2 delimiters next to each other.

For example, say the delimiter is comma.

`fashl,gasdf,agasdf,aasdf,,ghask`

Of the six tokens, the fifth token is empty. Its beginning and end are established by the fourth and fifth commas, therefore it is 'delimited'. But no characters were included in it.

---

However the sentence does go on to be ambiguous. 'Processing shall continue' does not specify what happens to the empty token. Or rather, it does not specify what logical action or path should be taken. So it could either mean:

1. If an empty token is found, continue to read until the next delimiter and consider that the token.
2. If an empty token is found, ignore the token and continue reading.

Though the end effect of that may not make a difference.